# caching id+username in memcacheD fails on cluster. too much data for NIC

Tags: sql, caching, memcached

I'm looking for a better solution.

I got a community with 200.000+ Users and a huge amount of SQL-Queries. Most of them includes an User-ID in its results. I need to workaround with a related username at output in most case.

[userId - username] is a separate table. To avoid tons of JOINS to this table, I decided to cache the hole table as an array in memcacheD. That worked fine at the beginning. The SQL-server load dropped a lot. everything runs really faster then before.

But, a few weeks later the hole server-cluster (5 webserver) got problems. The cached userid-username dataset becomes huge. so much that I reached the internal 1000Mbit data limit at network interfaces, while memcacheD was sending that records to requesting servers. I tried to serialize the data, but it didn't change a loot.

I see three ways to go now:

1) force memcacheD to cache the records on every single server. So the cluster does not need to request cache from another server. But every change in dataset needs to be done simultaneous on every server. - I don't know, if that is possible, anyway.

2) switch back to JOINS and work with cacheexecute.

3) you have a better solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you are using the cache in a way it was not intended to be used.  Memcached is best suited to be used as a key-value store, not a place to store a single large data element.  I would really think about whether you actually need this entire array with each individual call or whether you re-architect your data access pattern to simply retrieve the data you need to fulfill your request. In other words, if you have the username (from say a login) and need to get the user id, simply do a key lookup on that username to get only the user id needed.

In this sort of scenario however, I don't really understand what you are gaining by having the user id/username data in Memcached.  Do you have cases where the same user id's are being hit repeatedly such that you really maximize the benefit of having the data in a cache?  Are you not concerned over the volatility of having this data stored in memory as opposed to on disk in some sort of data persistence layer?

I guess I would really need to understand more about your use cases to give more concrete advice, but it just seems very odd to be trying to store and retrieve entire arrays of data.

Comment: I do not use the username to get the user-id. I use the user-id to get a username. i put the id-name array ($usernames) in memcached to avoid single sql-queries every time I need a username. Because I need them really really frequently.
So I thought it would be better for sql-performance to get the username-data out of a memcached array like this: $memUsernames[$sql[userId]]

So, what do you think about 200.000 memcached vars instead of one big array? eg. $user1 = anton, $user2  = charlie, ... sounds like crap to me, but maybe that's the way memcacheD works?

Comment: @Tom I think sending across an array of 200,000 items with every request is probably way worse performance-wise than even well designed SQL queries against well-implemented indexes (i.e. enough memory allocated to keep the entire index in memory as it should), and a well-implemented query cache.

Comment: now I tried to cache single items. One ID-array with regarding username (and userstatus). SQL crashes 2 seconds later, while getting thousands of requests for usernames. I also tried to cache all 220.000+ items before I did the live update, but it doesn't work. maybe because I cached them from different subdomain?

I'll try around tomorow.

Comment: @Tom just cache each user seperately in memcached, then 1 user is one get with a tiny result, also like mike said, your mysql server will try to hold all userdata in an index in memory anyways, so you might want to look at the memory the database has available to hold the indexes in memory